# Parsing specific XML elements with identical names in R

Tags: r, xml

I'm using the xml package in R to parse an XML document (snippet below).

xml snippet:

```
  <notes>
    <body xml="http://www.books.xhtml">
      <p> System: Mighty</p>
      <p>Confidence Level: </p>
    </body>
  </notes>
```

I'd like to just select the System: Mighty portion, and even just the Mighty part if possible. My code so far:

```
data <- xmlParse("abc.xml")
out_p <- getNodeSet(data, "//*[name()='p']", fun=xmlToList)
```

This results in a long list of all the p elements. System and Confidence Levels included. I've tried to play around with editing my code to select just the System elements, without success:

```
out_p <- getNodeSet(data, "//*p[attribute()[contains.,"SYSTEM"]", fun=xmlToList) ## doesn't work
```

What would be the correct way to exclude the Confidence level elements? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml2:

```r
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

xml <- ' <notes>
    <body xml="http://www.books.xhtml">
      <p> System: Mighty</p>
      <p>Confidence Level: </p>
    </body>
  </notes>'

xml %>% read_xml() %>% 
    xml_find_all('//p') %>%    # select p elements
    xml_text() %>%    # get node text
    grep('System:', ., value = TRUE) %>%    # select only matching text
    sub(' System: ', '', .)    # clean text
#> [1] "Mighty"
```

You could do more in `xml_find_all` with some more intense XPath, but this approach is easy to write and read. If this is actually HTML, you could use rvest instead of xml2; both work fine.